# How can i check that request is not empty

Tags: python, django

User press search button and search field is empty, He gets all the articles on the page.
code:

```
class SearchResultsView(ArticlesView):

def get_queryset(self, request):
    if request.POST.has_key('search'):
        return self.model.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=request.POST['search']) |
            Q(content__icontains=request.POST['search'])
            ).distinct()
    return []
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the `search` parameter and check if it is empty or not:

```
search = request.POST.get('search')
if search:
    return self.model.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=search) |
        Q(content__icontains=search)
        ).distinct()
```

`get()` would return `None` if search is not given. If `search` is passed as an empty string, the `if search` condition would not be satisfied since empty string is falsy by definition.